# linux & window socket programming (linux server, windows client)

Tags: linux, windows, sockets

I wanna connect linux server and windows client
These are simple(basic) example of linux server and windows client

These code work well in (linux server, linux client) and (windows server, window client)

(becuase, is it local ??)

How can I connect linux server and windows client??

(Case of linux, I executed codes in VirtualBox)

If client enter with port 55000, IP 127.0.0.1, they interaction, and change
some messages

`client.c` (windows)

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORT 55000
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int main() {
    WSADATA wsdata;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsdata) != 0) {
        printf("Fail to initiate ws2_d2.dll \n\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Success to initiate ws_32.dll\n\n");

    SOCKET clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddress;
    ZeroMemory(&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    ****************//VirtualBox IP '10.0.2.15'********************
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.2.15"); 

    if ((connect(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)(&serverAddress), sizeof(serverAddress)) != 0)) {
        printf("Fail to connect.\n\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("connected!!! \n\n");

    char toServer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    strcpy(toServer, "Hello Server!!! I'm client!");

    send(clientSocket, toServer, strlen(toServer) + 1, 0);

    printf("Data to server : %s\n\n", toServer);

    char fromServer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];

    recv(clientSocket, fromServer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

    printf("received data from server : %s\n", fromServer);

    closesocket(clientSocket);

    WSACleanup();
    printf("Exit ws_32.dll\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`server.c` (linux)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORT 55000

int main(){
    int server_socket;
    int client_socket;

    struct sockaddr_in server_address={0,};
    struct sockaddr_in client_address={0,};

    int client_address_size;

    char toClient[] = "Hello Client!!\n";
    char fromClient[100];

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("Server Socket Create!!!\n");

    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));

    server_address.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    bind(server_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
        sizeof(server_address));
    listen(server_socket, 5);

    printf("Wait Client...\n");
    client_address_size = sizeof(client_address);
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)%client_address
                            &client_address_size)
    printf("Client Connect!!!\n");

    read(client_socket, fromClient, sizeof(fromClient));
    printf("From Client Message: %s\n", fromClient);

    write(client_socket, toClient, sizeof(toClient));
    printf("To Client Message: %s\n", toClient);

    close(client_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with the correct IP address? 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address which points to the machine itself. There’s usually nothing in the code itself that wouldn’t work across machines if it works within one.

Comment: Thansk! so,  will ti be work to change '127.0.0.1'  to 'VirtualBox's IP' in the code 'serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");'?

Comment: and, additional environment setting is needed?

Comment: Yes, change that to point to the server’s IP address. Other changes should not be needed

Comment: Hmm.. I changed IP to 'VirtualBox IP '10.0.2.15'. but it didn't work!  Is there anything what I don't understand?

Comment: The server should listen on the "public" address, or listen to any (all). The client instead has to connect to (one of) the addresses the server is listening on. If you have a server inside a virtual machine, look at the interfaces inside that machine; then point your client to one of those addresses (but not 127.0.0.1!)